# Mixed model from SPSS doesn't produce same results in R? Am I miscoding something?

Tags: r, mixed-model, spss, nested-data

**TL/DR: I'm trying to convert a model from SPSS to R and I'm getting different results (Estimates of Fixed Effects), and I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Syntax, code, and results at the end.**

For my thesis, I am studying the effect of salt concentration in cooking water on pasta quality using three different types of pastas. So I have two factors, each with three levels (SALT concentration: 0%, 1%, 3%; Pasta TYPE: CP, RL, WT).

Only one pasta type and one salt concentration could be tested at a time. Each pot of pasta is therefore a BATCH. Two batches were prepared for each combination of factor levels (2 * 9).

A random selection of pieces from each batch were tested for quality. These are all recorded separately.

I assume the samples WITHIN each batch will be correlated and would like to account for this. The variation BETWEEN batches is random (i.e. the first batch for WT-1% should not be correlated with the first batch for CP-3%). Because of this, I have coded each batch individually (1-18) instead of 1-2.

**I figured out the model using SPSS, but I would like to switch over to R because I have 10 response variables to do this with, and I also have to deal with back-transforming data.**

#### Data Structure

```
> str(tpa_2)
'data.frame':   115 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Type     : Factor w/ 4 levels "CP","CP2","RL",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Batch    : Factor w/ 18 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Salt     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Replicate: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ bn2S     : num  -1.341 -0.502 -1.448 -1.02 -1.335 ...
 $ SampleID : Factor w/ 115 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

#### SPSS Model

```
MIXED bn2S BY SaltCode TypeCode 
  /CRITERIA=DFMETHOD(SATTERTHWAITE) CIN(95) MXITER(1000) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) 
    SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0.00001, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) 
  /FIXED = SaltCode TypeCode SaltCode*TypeCode | SSTYPE(3) 
  /METHOD = REML 
  /PRINT = CORB  SOLUTION 
  /RANDOM = INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(Batch) COVTYPE(VC).
```

#### R Model

```
library(afex)
m2<-mixed(bn2S ~Salt*Type + (1|Batch), data = tpa_2)
sum.m2<-summary(m2)
sum.m2
```

- *I get the same results with afex::mixed, lme4::lmer, and nlme::lme. The Anova Table wrapper from afex is structured like the Fixed Effects Tests table from SPSS.*

## Now onto the results.

I get significantly different results between SPSS and R.

#### SPSS Results

**Type III Tests of Fixed Effects**

| Source | Numerator df | Denominator df | F | Sig. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | 1 | 3.594 | 18.178 | .016 |
| SaltCode | 2 | 3.310 | 3.974 | .132 |
| TypeCode | 3 | 2.641 | 272.032 | <.001 |
| SaltCode * TypeCode | 6 | 2.348 | 4.217 | .174 |

**Estimates of Fixed Effects** a

| Parameter | Estimate | Std. Error | df | t | Sig. | 95% CI Lower Bound | 95% CI Upper Bound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | .877 | .100 | 3.616 | 8.790 | .001 | .588 | 1.165 |
| [SaltCode=1] | .591 | .156 | 5.187 | 3.785 | .012 | .194 | .988 |
| [SaltCode=2] | .548 | .151 | 4.750 | 3.628 | .017 | .154 | .943 |
| [SaltCode=3] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [TypeCode=1] | -1.965 | .165 | 3.017 | -11.891 | .001 | -2.489 | -1.441 |
| [TypeCode=2] | -1.827 | .151 | 2.077 | -12.114 | .006 | -2.454 | -1.201 |
| [TypeCode=3] | -.817 | .130 | 2.604 | -6.279 | .012 | -1.270 | -.365 |
| [TypeCode=4] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=1] * [TypeCode=1] | -.599 | .282 | 6.340 | -2.128 | .075 | -1.280 | .081 |
| [SaltCode=1] * [TypeCode=2] | -.771 | .226 | 2.593 | -3.410 | .052 | -1.560 | .017 |
| [SaltCode=1] * [TypeCode=3] | -.370 | .208 | 3.902 | -1.779 | .152 | -.953 | .213 |
| [SaltCode=1] * [TypeCode=4] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=2] * [TypeCode=1] | -.590 | .245 | 3.657 | -2.407 | .080 | -1.297 | .116 |
| [SaltCode=2] * [TypeCode=2] | -.747 | .223 | 2.474 | -3.352 | .058 | -1.550 | .056 |
| [SaltCode=2] * [TypeCode=3] | .019 | .196 | 3.369 | .097 | .928 | -.569 | .607 |
| [SaltCode=2] * [TypeCode=4] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=3] * [TypeCode=1] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=3] * [TypeCode=2] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=3] * [TypeCode=3] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |
| [SaltCode=3] * [TypeCode=4] | 0b | 0 | . | . | . | . | . |

b. This parameter is set to zero because it is redundant.

#### R Results

`nice(m2)`

**Mixed Model Anova Table (Type 3 tests, S-method)**
Model: bn2S ~ Salt * Type + (1 | Batch)
Data: tpa_2

| Effect | df | F | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Salt | 2, 3.02 | 3.97 | .143 |
| Type | 3, 2.93 | 272.03 | <.001 |
| Salt:Type | 6, 2.70 | 4.22 | .150 |

`summary(m2)`

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's
method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: bn2S ~ Salt * Type + (1 | Batch)
Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 105.3

**Scaled residuals:**

| Min | 1Q | Median | 3Q | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.2729 | -0.6207 | 0.0923 | 0.6020 | 2.5393 |

**Random effects:**

| Groups | Name | Variance | Std.Dev. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Batch | (Intercept) | 0.002186 | 0.04675 |
| Residual |  | 0.106238 | 0.32594 |

Number of obs: 115, groups:  Batch, 18

**Fixed effects:**

| Factor | Estimate | Std. Error | df | t value | Pr(>t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | -0.15094 | 0.03540 | 3.59414 | -4.264 | 0.01633 |
| Salt1 | 0.03086 | 0.05363 | 4.66163 | 0.575 | 0.59167 |
| Salt2 | 0.09404 | 0.04908 | 3.34529 | 1.916 | 0.14169 |
| Type1 | -0.95426 | 0.07357 | 5.09880 | -12.972 | 4.24e-05 |
| Type2 | -0.92612 | 0.05933 | 2.11691 | -15.611 | 0.00320 |
| Type3 | 0.47305 | 0.05277 | 3.12594 | 8.965 | 0.00249 |
| Salt1:Type1 | -0.02260 | 0.11533 | 7.69583 | -0.196 | 0.84970 |
| Salt2:Type1 | -0.11903 | 0.09941 | 4.24753 | -1.197 | 0.29371 |
| Salt1:Type2 | -0.08504 | 0.08645 | 2.37978 | -0.984 | 0.41446 |
| Salt2:Type2 | -0.16617 | 0.08371 | 2.10267 | -1.985 | 0.17928 |
| Salt1:Type3 | -0.07265 | 0.07992 | 3.89972 | -0.909 | 0.41597 |
| Salt2:Type3 | 0.21058 | 0.07339 | 3.00943 | 2.869 | 0.06385 |

#### Is it possible that the issue has to do with SPSS designating the Batches as Subjects? Is that not coming through correctly in my R model?

Comment: It seems that SPSS and R use different denominator mean squares to get F-ratios to test some of the main effects. In both software programs, try to look at complete ANOVA tables that give all mean squares and F ratios to check for such differences.

Comment: The F statistics seem to be the same, but the degrees-of-freedom estimates for the F tests differ between the SPSS and R outputs. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108161/28500) for an introduction. SPSS and R make different default assumptions about the reference level of a categorical predictor; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/263425/28500). That would alter  the detailed table of estimates unless you took pains to specify the same reference levels. Furthermore, with 10 response variables you need to take correlations among them into account.