# How to interpret output of a moderation with 2 moderators (1 Dichotomous, 1 continuous) and a dichotomous predictor?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have conducted a moderation analysis with two independent moderators. (Using Hayes Process model 2). I have attached the output for your reference.

I am looking for the impact that financial wellbeing and gender has the relationship between marital status and loneliness.
My variables are:

- Y: Loneliness (continuous variable - low values indicating low
  loneliness)
- X: Marital status (single or married- dummy coded to have    single
  as the reference category)
- W (mod1): Financial wellbeing
  (continuous- low values indicating low financial wellbeing)
- Z (mod2): Gender (male or female- dummy coded to have male as the
  reference    category)

All the p-values show significance

I have two questions:

1. Is this selection of variables appropriate for the moderation analysis I am undertaking? Is the combination of a  dichotomous predictor and moderator suitable for this?
2. Can someone please help me interpret the output? When looking at the conditional effect, I am seeing all the values under 'effect' are negative- some closer to 0 than others but I am not sure how to interpret this in relation to the dichotomous predictor (being single coded as 0).

[image: Moderation Output 1]
[image: Moderation Output 2]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the program output as text. If you paste text into the editor, select it, and use the code `{}` tool, it's easier to read than in a picture, values can be copied for further analysis, and those who use speech-to-text can "see" the values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Each time I copy the text into the question to edit - it forces it into an image format without the option to use the code tool. Even when first selecting the code tool to then copy and paste the output in -It still wants to convert it into an image. I'm unsure why it's doing that and how to prevent it, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear model with two interaction terms, expressed in R formula syntax as:

```
Y ~ X + W + Z + X:W + X:Z
```

The "moderation" is via the interaction terms `X:W` and `X:Z`, with `X` (marital status here) being of primary interest but with individual terms also needed for `W` and `Z`. Interactions are possible in principle between categorical predictors, continuous predictors, or any combination, so you have no problem there. The interaction terms are simply products of the included predictor-variable values.

I'm not sure, however, how this PROCESS Procedure works together with standard SPSS [coding of categorical predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263595/28500) like `X` and `Z` here. The SPSS default is to express coefficients as differences from the highest level of a categorical predictor, unlike R which uses differences from the lowest level. You will have to check the manual(s) or play with some example data to determine whether, for example, the coefficient for `Z` (Male) is for (Male - Female) or (Female - Male). (Highly software-specific questions are off-topic on this site.)

For the "conditional effects," each "Effect" is the difference associated with marital-status difference at the indicated combination of the moderators. Again, whether that's for (Married - Single) or (Single - Married) is a question of how SPSS and this PROCESS Procedure together are handling categorical predictors.

With such a large sample it's not surprising that all your results are "statistically significant." You have to use your understanding of the subject matter to gauge whether they are practically significant.